# Including QRGen in pom.xml

Tags: maven, qr-code

I'm developing app in spring + hibernate in maven and I need to make QR codes so
I've found this tutorial http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-qr-codes-java-servlet-qr-code-java/
In that tutorial following libs are in use:
xzing and qrgen (net.glxn.qrgen)

I've added in pom.xml dependency on xzing and its running but qrgen needs his own repo so
I've included repository like on that page: http://kenglxn.github.com/QRGen/ :
but it seems that http://kenglxn.github.com/QRGen/repository is down

Anyone knows new (or exact) repo address or could tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Seems to be missing. Why don't you clone the git repo and build yourself? That is at least a short term solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version 1.2 is now available from maven central http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.glxn%7Cqrgen%7C1.2%7Cjar

please use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
    <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have a third party JAR that is not available in a (public) repository. Best would be if you had a company wide repository that you use as proxy. It is quite easy to set up Nexus for this task. Then you can import the JAR to that repository (e.g. Nexus has a default "3rd party library" repository setting). If you don't have such a repository you need to import the JAR to your local repository but this restricts successfull builds to your machine - obviously not what you want when you use Maven. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for the syntax for a local import.

Of course you could set up a network drive as a company wide repo, some think this is easier than setting up Nexus or any other repo server. Trust me, it is not worth it, do it the right way from the beginning.

Comment: For now I've included source .java files from that jar into my project

Comment: You should at least set up a library project for the other sources and reference that in your project's build path settings.