# QRGen library import can not be resolved

Tags: java, import, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to generate QR-Codes in Java with the QRGen library and ZXing. I followed the instructions on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257038/how-to-create-qrcode-using-java-j2se). 
I included the following three libraries:

zxing-core-1.7.jar ,
zxing-javase-1.7.jar ,
qrgen-1.0.jar

and also added them to the build path.

However the import `net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode` from the QRGen library can not be resolved. Therefore I can't use methods such as `QRCode.from("...")` etc.

Does anyone have an idea why this import does not work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v 1.2 is available through maven central.

see this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195951/439021